# What is the proper way to say "to use/open an umbrella"?

Tags: verbs

I have the following options:

傘を_______

1. かけます
2. します
3. あびます
4. 差します (さします)

But I'd like to know which is the correct one and why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We say 傘をさす, but さす is **差す** in kanji. 傘をさす is a set phrase you have to learn by rote. 傘をする is occasionally used in reality, too, but it may be considered wrong in exams. 傘をかける means "to hang an umbrella (on a hook)". We virtually never say 傘を浴びる in daily life.

This usage of 差す corresponds to the [sixth definition of 差す in jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B7%AE%E3%81%99). You may want to remember a similar set phrase, 刀を差す "to bear a sword (in one's belt)".

(Verbs like する, とる, かける, さす and so on have lots of usages. Practically, you have to remember which verb is used with which noun. Usages of common verbs in English are [often arbitrary and confusing to learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42909/8629), too.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So the answer is: 傘をさす, none of the above?

Comment: @Kutyel Or 傘を差す in kanji. Maybe someone who made this question made some mistake?

Comment: Original question: https://twitter.com/akokitamura/status/1279891802565128193

Comment: @Kutyel So it's a mistype on your side.

Comment: True, corrected now :)

Comment: さす is the plain form conjugation and さします is the polite form conjugation, but they are the same verb. So the right answer is the 4th one.

Comment: Answer by OP: https://twitter.com/akokitamura/status/1280285158608793600?s=20&t=AkkWgoZNM6Yo6sf7QZfUzg